# Spicules vs Prominences/filaments

Tags: the-sun

What is the difference between spicules and prominences/filaments. I know that they are both in the chromosphere, and I know the difference between provinces and filaments (depends on the view), but how are spicules different?

Answer (score 1):

Spicules are much smaller, more dynamic, and possibly hotter. They are also much more abundant. While the term spicules is strictly defined for objects off the solar limb, their disk counterparts (let's call them fibrils for simplicity) cover the whole Sun, all the time. Spicules have lifetimes of a few minutes and extend up to ~15 Mm, with the most energetic of them being ejected with speeds of around 100 km/s.

While prominences/filaments have a relatively stable temperature around 10,000 K, spicules/filaments are also seen in filters sensitive to temperatures around 100,000 K, meaning that some of them will undergo a thermal evolution to at least the transition region.

Spicules/fibrils are a candidate for energy and mass deposition in the corona.